# How to do a wordcount on every row of a CSV file?

Tags: r

I have a CSV file with an `ID` field and a `TEXT` field . I need to add a third field with the word count of the `TEXT` field on every row.
How should I proceed?

Example:  If this is my starting data frame

```
  ID                                 TEXT
1  1           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
2  2           Praesent venenatis nisl id
3  3 Nunc dapibus maximus vulputate. Nunc
```

then the desired result is

```
  ID                                 TEXT WordCount
1  1           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet         5
2  2           Praesent venenatis nisl id         4
3  3 Nunc dapibus maximus vulputate. Nunc         5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the handy `stri_count_words()` function from the *stringi* package.

```
df$WordCount <- stringi::stri_count_words(df$TEXT)
```

which gives

```
  ID                                 TEXT WordCount
1  1           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet         5
2  2           Praesent venenatis nisl id         4
3  3 Nunc dapibus maximus vulputate. Nunc         5
```

However in base R, you could split on the spaces with `strsplit()` after removing the punctuation, then take the lengths of the list elements.

```
lengths(strsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", df$TEXT), "\\s+"))
# [1] 5 4 5
```

Or, as @David suggests, just count the spaces and add 1.  `trimws()` is used to remove any errant spaces that may be lurking at the beginning or end of the string.

```
lengths(gregexpr("\\s+", trimws(df$TEXT))) + 1L
# [1] 5 4 5
```